# Accidentally installed SharePointServices 3.0 on a live MOSS2007 box

Tags: sharepoint

Was working with two RDP windows and meant to install SharePointServices 3.0 on a new dev box but accidentally installed it on the live farm web server running MOSS2007.

All sharepoint sites now simply read 
Server error: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=96177

Central Administration still shows all the old shared services but they errors with the same as above when you click on them.

What happens if I run SharePointServices again and go to repair -> remove? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably detached your Sharepoint server from the config database, and effectively from your farm.

So what I would do is this:

- Backup all your Sharepoint databases (you *already* have a backup of this right?)
- Uninstall Office Sharepoint Server
- Uninstall Sharepoint Services
- Reinstall Office Sharepoint Server
- Reinstall any Service Packs and hotfixes you already applied
- Run the Sharepoint Products and Technologies Configuration Wizard and point it at your config database.

That should get you back up and running.

Probably a good idea to change the background colour of your production servers so you have a very obvious visual cue where you are running a particular command!

Comment: "change the background colour of your production servers" - hells yes.

Answer (score 3):

If it's worth more than $250, call Microsoft Support.

Answer (score 1):

Since it was a live box, you should have a backup. Restore it.